# After generating dummy variables?

Tags: r, pca, data-analysis, dummy-variable

I am trying to change the category variables into dummy variables. "season","holiday","workingday","weather","temp","atemp","humidity","windspeed", "registered","count","hour","dow" are all variables.

Here is my code:

```
#dummy
library(dummies)
#set up new dummy variables
data.new = data.frame(data)
data.new = cbind(data.new,dummy(data.new$season, sep = "_"))
data.new = cbind(data.new,dummy(data.new$holiday, sep = "_"))
data.new = cbind(data.new,dummy(data.new$weather, sep = "_"))
data.new = cbind(data.new,dummy(data.new$dow, sep = "_"))
data.new = cbind(data.new,dummy(data.new$hour, sep = "_"))
data.new = cbind(data.new,dummy(data.new$workingday, sep = "_"))
#delete the old variables
data.new = data.new[,-1]
data.new = data.new[,-1]
data.new = data.new[,-2]
data.new = data.new[,-8]
data.new = data.new[,-8]
data.new = data.new[,-1]
```

Should I delete the old variables after generating the dummy variables? 
If I want to do PCR, may I use all variables, e.g.

```
fit = pcr(count~.,data = data.new)
```

to generate a linear regression model? 
Or should I just use the not dummy variables?

```
fit = pcr(count~temp+atemp+humidity+windspeed+registered,data = data.new)
```

Sorry to cause your misunderstanding. I used lm function as an example. Now I have changed it into pcr function.
Thank you for reading this question!

Comment: Try to use `dummy.data.frame` to create your dummy variables in your dataset. Deleting or not deleting the original variables is up to you and how are you going to specify the formula.

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean that my code is wrong to use cbind function and dummy function? I am really new to coding. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: It's just that this function will create multiple dummy variables for you if you specify the variable names. See how the function works when you run `?dummy.data.frame`

Comment: `lm` automatically generates the dummies for you if your variables are character or factor, so it is not necessary to create your own dummies. Just write `fit = lm(count~.,data = data.new) ` without all the `dummy` lines.

Comment: @ AntoniosK: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your categorical variables are factors, the `lm` function will handle the creation of dummy variables for you.

I would recommend you first verify that your data is a `data.frame` and the predictors that are categorical are indeed factors.

```
class(data)
sapply(data, class)
```

Or more simply

```
str(data)
```

Then, simply put them in your formula in your `lm` call.

```
fit = lm(count ~ season + holiday + workingday + weather + temp + atemp + humidity + windspeed + registered + hour + dow, data=data)
```

Or if the columns in the formula are the only ones in your `data.frame` then you can use the short-hand.

```
fit = lm(count ~ ., data=data)
```

Comment: Got it. But if I am not using lm function, I am using PCR after generating the dummy variables? Should I write a code like this? pcr.fit=pcr(count~.,data = train, scale = FALSE, validation = "CV") Or should I use this code?pcr.fit=pcr(count~temp+atemp+humidity+windspeed+registered,data = train, scale = FALSE, validation = "CV")

Comment: In general, you should exclude categorical variables from standard PCA, there are several discussions available surrounding this, here is one such one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont